# How can I prevent the user from resizing the silverlight out-of-browser window?

Tags: silverlight, resize, height, width, out-of-browser

I have a **silverlight** app which can be installed as **out-of-browser**.

I've defined the Height and Width in the main **UserControl**.

I've defined the same Height and Width in the **OutOfBrowserSettings.xml** file.

**But the user can still resize the out-of-browser frame window. How do I prevent this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window hosting the Silverlight application cannot be controlled by the application when it is running with normal permissions, that would be a security issue.

However, if you install the OOB application with elevated permissions, you can change the chrome of the window and define your own. This will prevent the resizing (except of course if you explicitly implement resizing with the custom chrome).

To change the chrome options, use the OOB Settings in the project properties.

[image: Changing OOB properties]

Answer (score 2):

I did not want to give up the window border. This is not pretty, but here is what I am doing for now.

```
    Host.Content.Resized += new EventHandler(Content_Resized);
    ...
    void Content_Resized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
        {
            MainWindow.Width = 800;
            MainWindow.Height = 448;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  It seems to be another one of those "User is King" choices.