# Disable resizing out of browser Silverlight 4 Window

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser, maximize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent the user from resizing the silverlight out-of-browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682731/how-can-i-prevent-the-user-from-resizing-the-silverlight-out-of-browser-window)

Is there any way to actually remove the ability to maximize/resize the out of browser window since I want my application to be of a certain size.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682731/how-can-i-prevent-the-user-from-resizing-the-silverlight-out-of-browser-window

Comment: I'd find it quite annoying not to be able to resize a window on my desktop :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure but I would hazard a guess you could just go:

```
this.resizable = false;
this.maximise = FALSE;
```

in the constructor of the views code behind file.

Answer (score -3):

You can make any new window have no statusbar, no toolbar, no resize, etc. using window.open():
http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

However, this is completely dependent on the browser, many ignore this, or have a user setting to override this behavior.

Comment: I think you didn't understand his question. He asked some thing else. Rollback or delete your question unless some downvotes you

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript. Read the question.